# Popup menu like Facebook For editing/ deleting/spam post

Tags: android, listview, drop-down-menu, popup

[listview item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkUEI.png)

Popup-menu :

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.edusols.HomeActivity" >

    <item
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:id="@+id/one"
       android:title="abcd" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="Two"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:title="Three"/>

</menu>
```

- I have a listview, i have option like edit post and all that
- I want popup-menu on particular position, i am getting pop-up menu but not at correct position
- I have set pop-up menu in listview adapter

code:

```
ivOptionMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (post_user_id.equals(preferenceHelper.getID()))
                {

                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, ivOptionMenu);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    popup.show();//showing popup menu
                }
                else {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, ivOptionMenu);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    popup.show();//showing popup menu
                }
```

[How menu appears on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfxdX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PopMenuConstructor(ctx,**view**)
**view** by which **PopMenu will connected**.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (post_user_id.equals(preferenceHelper.getID())) {
            //PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, ivOptionMenu);
            //change to this
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, v);
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create xml file in /res/menu/**popup_menu.xml** and add these code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action1"
        android:title="delete" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action2"
        android:title="properties" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action3"
        android:title="add to queue" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action4"
        android:title="play next" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action5"
        android:title="add to favorite" />
</menu>
```

**Use this code in java file:**

```
mViewHolder.imagemore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(context, v);
                    menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menu.getMenu());
                    menu.show();

                    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                                case R.id.action1:

                                    deleteSong(position);

                                    break;
                                case R.id.action2:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "your desire action is " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action3:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "your desire action is " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action4:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "your desire action is " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action5:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "your desire action is " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```